# STS 4 Boot Dashboard properties not showing request mappings and beans

Tags: spring-tools-4

When I start the application and go to Dashboard > Properties > Request Mappings I do not see any mappings.

The message shown is
 must be running with JMX enabled; and actuator 'mappings' endpoint must be enabled to obtain request mappings.

Neither are the beans showing up.

properties enabled (YML)-

spring:  jmx:   enabled: true

also, I can view the mappings and beans using the actuator urls /beans and /mappings using postman.

How can I see them in STS itself?

Comment: the YML syntax in the project is correct, one below the other. Here I could not display it properly

Comment: maybe attach a sample project with a shared launch config? then we could have a more detailed look... :-)

Answer (score 0):

I found that this setting can causes the problem:

```
endpoints:
  jmx:
    unique-names: true
```